# xslt cannot assign a param with a boolean value within `<xsl:choose>`

Tags: xml, xslt, exslt

this code is giving me the output `test` when the expected output should be nothing..

Is it something wrong with my XSLT processor or..? :

```
    <xsl:template match="/">

         <xsl:param name="IsTextArea">
     <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="false()">
           <xsl:value-of select="true()"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
           <xsl:value-of select="false()"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:param>

  <html>

   <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="$IsTextArea">test
   </xsl:when>
   </xsl:choose>


  </html>
    </xsl:template>
```

Btw i need a solution for *raw XSLT 1.0* (no extensions and stuff like that).

Is it possible to set a boolean parameter for a `param` in XSLT 1.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your parameter is evaluating to a string. You should use:

```
    <html>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$IsTextArea = 'true'">
                test
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$IsTextArea"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </html>
```

Comment: btw is it ok if i set it to `1` and `0` and use `$IsTextArea=1` ?

Comment: No. As @Michael-Key correctly stated, you are going to have always a string. Try it :)!

Answer (score 3):

The xsl:value-of instruction converts whatever you give it to a string. So true() becomes "true", and false() becomes "false". When you use a string in a boolean context, any non-empty string becomes true(), while "" becomes false(). So boolean->string->boolean conversion doesn't round-trip. In XSLT 2.0 the answer is to use xsl:sequence instead of xsl:value-of; in 1.0, just use strings like "yes" and "no" to avoid confusion.

Comment: sorry could you elaborate on the `xsl:sequence` part? do you mean that we will set a sequence with 1 item which is a boolean?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be like this:

```
<xsl:param name="IsTextArea">
 <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="false()">
       <xsl:value-of select="false()"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:value-of select="true()"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
```

Are think your true and false were out of place.

Comment: nop they aren't out of place. since the test is `false()` IsTextArea should be `false()` then (see the code in my question). and the check should fail. Yet it succeeded and this is verified since `test` was displayed.